# Loading JSON data gives undefined object in Angular 2 - asynchronous?

Tags: json, asynchronous, angular, typescript

...component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ValgteSkolerService } from '../valgteSkoler.service';
import { DatoService } from './datoer.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'kalender',
    providers: [DatoService],
    templateUrl: 'app/kalendervisning/html/kalender.html'
})
export class KalenderComponent {

    private valgteSkoleRuter: Array<any> = [];
    public datoer: any[] = [];

    constructor(private valgteSkolerService: ValgteSkolerService, private DatoService: DatoService) {
        this.DatoService
        .getDato()
        .subscribe(datoer => { this.datoer = datoer; });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.valgteSkolerService.hentLagretData();
      this.valgteSkoleRuter = this.valgteSkolerService.delteValgteSkoleRuter;
    }

    antallRuter: number = 0;
    j: number = 0;

    ukeEn(mnd: number, aar: number) :Cell[] {
        var cells: Array<Cell> = [];
        this.antallRuter = 0;
        for (this.j = 1; this.j <= this.antallDager(mnd, aar); this.j++) {
            var cell = new Cell;
            console.log(this.datoer[this.j].dato);
            cell.id = this.datoer[this.j].dato;
            cell.text = this.j;       
            cells.push(cell);
            this.antallRuter++;
            this.j = this.j;
            if (this.antallRuter % 7 == 0 && this.antallRuter != 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return cells;
    }

class Cell {
    id: string;
    text: number;
}
```

...service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DatoService { 

    dato: Array<any>;

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

        getDato() {
            return this.http.request('app/kalendervisning/datoer.json')
                 .map(res => res.json());
        }   
}
```

...json:

```
{
        "dato": "2016-08-01"
    },
etc.
```

I am struggling with the `cell.id = this.datoer[this.j].dato` statement in the component. 
I have checked the browser inspector, and it seems like the `datoer` array is undefined until the whole code has been run through several times. After a while, the array gets filled up. When I tested this with console.log, it prints 9 undefined objects, and then the actual data, but for some reason repeated 2 times also.
I think there might be a problem that the data is not loaded asynchronously, but I'm not sure. 
Are there any ideas why it acts like this, and do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

add constrctor code of calling API inside `ngOnInit` :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.DatoService
    .getDato()
    .subscribe(datoer => { this.datoer = datoer; });

  this.valgteSkolerService.hentLagretData();
  this.valgteSkoleRuter =     this.valgteSkolerService.delteValgteSkoleRuter;
}
```

Comment: when `ukeEn` is called ?

Comment: In the HTML template.

Comment: put the last 2 lines inside the subscribe - and for the html template you could use a boolean loaded = false and set it after everything in the subscribe to true - then you only need a *ngIf="loaded" where your datoer is needed

Comment: You mean just cut and paste the 2 lines into the {} brackets inside the subscribe? Still getting an error with undefined. I didn't get the last part, feel free to post a more detailed answer.

Comment: Ok, first I need to know where you are triggering the ukeEn function

Comment: I already commented the answer above. In the HTML file (template).

Comment: <td *ngFor="let cell of ukeEn(8, 2016)" 
                [attr.title]="cell.id">{{cell.text}}</td>